# Encrypting Password With Windows Form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, encryption

I was wondering if anyone is able to guide me in the right direction as to how to encrypt passwords given by a windows form in VB.net. I am fairly new to programming so some specialist terms may not make sense. I also store the username and password in an access database. Should this be encrypted? If so how? Or should i encrypt the password before pressing enter so that the encrypted value is stored? Any help or information whatsoever will be appreciated. I will respond quickly to any questions you may have in order to provide you with further information. I will provide my code now, (as i do not think it is of relevance) ::::::

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form3

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Complete All Fields")
    Else
        Try
            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Computer Science\CA\tyre_stock_database_21.accdb")
            Dim insert As String = "Insert into login_info values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "');"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Account Successfully Created")
            Me.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message))
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: This is a useful article: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). It may look like a lot to go through, but it is very readable and will give you a good start.

Comment: Hashing is the way to go as Andrew said, encrypted data can be unencrypted, so it's usually preferable to 1-way-hash the password and store that. When a user needs to log in, you only need to check that the hash of what they entered matches the hash you have stored in your database. If you're looking for an easy implementation, the bcrypt.net nuget package is one of the simplest to use I've seen. It handles adding the salt and returns a single hash string for you to store, and has two easy function calls to hash a password and to validate a password.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I’ll take a look thank you so much!

Comment: @soohoonigan this was very helpful thanks again :)

Comment: Also look into SQL Parameters - that has not been the correct way to build SQL for many years

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [security](https:/security.stackexchange.com); designing your security should be performed before programming the solution. Searching for "password storage" online would probably be a good first step.